# Bugzilla : No SASL mechanism found

Tags: email, smtp, perl, bugzilla

I am using Bugzilla on windows 7.

I am using the [unofficial Bugzilla installer](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32InstallPackages). I followed the steps accordingly and gave valid credentials wherever required.

I open Bugzilla and try to create a new account , but i get the following error.

```
Software error:
No SASL mechanism found
at C:/Program Files/Bugzilla/perl/perl/site/lib/Authen/SASL.pm line 77
at C:/Program Files/Bugzilla/perl/perl/lib/Net/SMTP.pm line 143
```

i ran checksetup.pl and found that Authen::SASL and SMTP both are available on my machine.

The output of checksetup.pl is as follows.

```
* This is Bugzilla 3.6.3 on perl 5.10.1
* Running on Win7 Build 7600

Checking perl modules...
Checking for              CGI.pm (v3.33)   ok: found v3.49
Checking for          Digest-SHA (any)     ok: found v5.48
Checking for            TimeDate (v2.21)   ok: found v2.24
Checking for            DateTime (v0.28)   ok: found v0.53
Checking for   DateTime-TimeZone (v0.79)   ok: found v1.10
Checking for                 DBI (v1.41)   ok: found v1.609
Checking for    Template-Toolkit (v2.22)   ok: found v2.22
Checking for          Email-Send (v2.16)   ok: found v2.198
Checking for          Email-MIME (v1.861)  ok: found v1.903
Checking for Email-MIME-Encodings (v1.313)  ok: found v1.313
Checking for Email-MIME-Modifier (v1.442)  ok: found v1.903
Checking for                 URI (any)     ok: found v1.52

Checking available perl DBD modules...
Checking for              DBD-Pg (v1.45)   ok: found v2.16.1
Checking for           DBD-mysql (v4.00)   ok: found v4.012
Checking for          DBD-Oracle (v1.19)    not found

The following Perl modules are optional:
Checking for                  GD (v1.20)   ok: found v2.44
Checking for               Chart (v2.1)    ok: found v2.4.1
Checking for         Template-GD (any)     ok: found v1.56
Checking for          GDTextUtil (any)     ok: found v0.86
Checking for             GDGraph (any)     ok: found v1.44
Checking for            XML-Twig (any)     ok: found v3.34
Checking for          MIME-tools (v5.406)  ok: found v5.427
Checking for         libwww-perl (any)     ok: found v5.834
Checking for         PatchReader (v0.9.4)  ok: found v0.9.5
Checking for           perl-ldap (any)     ok: found v0.39
Checking for         Authen-SASL (any)     ok: found v2.15
Checking for          RadiusPerl (any)     ok: found v0.17
Checking for           SOAP-Lite (v0.710.06) ok: found v0.710.10
Checking for            JSON-RPC (any)     ok: found v0.95
Checking for          Test-Taint (any)     ok: found v1.04
Checking for         HTML-Parser (v3.40)   ok: found v3.64
Checking for       HTML-Scrubber (any)     ok: found v0.08
Checking for Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper (any)     ok: found v1.316
Checking for         Email-Reply (any)     ok: found v1.202
Checking for         TheSchwartz (any)      not found
Checking for      Daemon-Generic (any)      not found
Checking for            mod_perl (v1.999022)  not found
***********************************************************************
* OPTIONAL MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Certain Perl modules are not required by Bugzilla, but by           *
* installing the latest version you gain access to additional         *
* features.                                                           *
*                                                                     *
* The optional modules you do not have installed are listed below,    *
* with the name of the feature they enable. Below that table are the  *
* commands to install each module.                                    *
***********************************************************************
*    MODULE NAME * ENABLES FEATURE(S)                                 *
***********************************************************************
*    TheSchwartz * Mail Queueing                                      *
* Daemon-Generic * Mail Queueing                                      *
*       mod_perl * mod_perl                                           *
***********************************************************************
* Note For Windows Users                                              *
***********************************************************************
* In order to install the modules listed below, you first have to run *
* the following command as an Administrator:                          *
*                                                                     *
*   ppm repo add theory58S http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/PPMPackages/10xx/
*                                                                     *
* Then you have to do (also as an Administrator):                     *
*                                                                     *
*   ppm repo up theory58S                                             *
*                                                                     *
* Do that last command over and over until you see "theory58S" at the *
* top of the displayed list.                                          *
***********************************************************************
COMMANDS TO INSTALL OPTIONAL MODULES:

    TheSchwartz: ppm install TheSchwartz
 Daemon-Generic: ppm install Daemon-Generic
       mod_perl: ppm install mod_perl

Reading ./localconfig...
Checking for           DBD-mysql (v4.00)   ok: found v4.012
Checking for           MySQL (v4.1.2)  ok: found v5.1.44-community-log

Removing existing compiled templates...
Precompiling templates...done.

Now that you have installed Bugzilla, you should visit the 'Parameters'
page (linked in the footer of the Administrator account) to ensure it
is set up as you wish - this includes setting the 'urlbase' option to
the correct URL.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Please tell me what should i do.

**Please note: i am running behind a corporate proxy , SSL/TLS is not used internally but i am giving the smtpUser and smtpPass also.**

Comment: which mail server are you using ?

Comment: The Unofficial Windows Bugzilla comes configured with **SMTP** , i suppose this means the local SMTP Server needs to be present, and **Sendmail**, an option to add a third party Mail Transfer Agent.I am not able to get either of them working.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely cause is that your library is missing Authen::SASL::Perl::NTLM

Please refer to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625781 for details.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have configured your Bugzilla system to authenticate with a SASL system when sending e-mail but the specifics for your SASL system has not been configured.

From the Bugzilla Guide:

```
3.1.12. Email

This page contains all of the parameters for configuring how Bugzilla
deals with the email notifications it sends. See below for a summary of
important options.

...

smtp_username
      Username to use for SASL authentication to the SMTP server.
      Leave this parameter empty if your server does not require
      authentication.

smtp_password
      Password to use for SASL authentication to the SMTP server. This
      parameter will be ignored if the "smtp_username" parameter is
      left empty.
```

Comment: "Leave this parameter empty if your server does not require authentication." Is key, my SMTP does not require a password and I had erroneously set the username by following a git send-email tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Authen/SASL.pm line 77.
at /usr/share/perl5/Net/SMTP.pm line 143.
```

For me Resolved

For this error please do below setting for Microsft Exchage emaild to Using TLS ot SSL/ Follow below stops

For windows Users

```
CPAN: install Net::SMTP::TLS
```

Linuix Users /

```
cpan install Email::Send::SMTP::TLS

cp Mailer.pm Mailer.pm_Bkp
```

Make changes in below file

```
vim /usr/share/bugzilla/Bugzilla/Mailer.pm 
use Email::Send;
```

### Use this any one of sting  below or above one to communicate SMTP  TLS

```
use Email::Send::SMTP::TLS;

sub MessageToMTA {
my ($smtp_server, $smtp_port);
}

if ($method eq "SMTP" | | $method eq "SMTP::TLS") {
    ($smtp_server,$smtp_port) = split /:/,Bugzilla->params->{"smtpserver"};
        push @args, 
        Host  => $smtp_server,
                       user => Bugzilla->params->{"smtp_username"},
                       password => Bugzilla->params->{"smtp_password"},
                      Hello => $hostname,
                      Debug => Bugzilla->params->{'smtp_debug'};
      push @args, Port => $smtp_port if($smtp_port);
}
:wq
```

Save this file .

Run below command to verify error before check the url :

```
./checksetup.pl
```

Now check it it’s should work.